# Winhttp .body.innerhml not as . Responsetext

Tags: html, excel, vba, httpresponse, winhttprequest

I m using vba and i m able to scrape from web , get data , pur in Access or excel and so on..
I ve scraped Just a lot of Page on a intranet web using winhttp. Send get response text and surf trough . Body.innerhtml.
Now in One and only Page i can take all the contento of the Page in a .TXT or .HTML file but i can t get Grom . Body.innwrhtml...
It seen as It truncated or not ready cooerctly..
Any ideas?
Thanks for all'.

UPDATE: I TRY INSERT CODE TAKES FROM RESPONSETEXT ( I VE JUST REMOVE PARAGRAPHS ^p BECAUSE CHARACHTERS WAS OVER POST LIMIT)

I HAVE TO GET HTML FROM THIS TABLE `<table width="100%" class="base" summary="La tabella riporta i dati del documento">`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> <HTML lang="it"><HEAD><META name="GENERATOR" content="IBM Software Development Platform"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"><META http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate"><META http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"><META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"><!--  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>--><!--  includo CSS di Base e Applicazione --><LINK REL=STYLESHEET TYPE="text/css" HREF="/Sito/consultazioni/css/ApplicazioneUffici.css"><LINK REL=STYLESHEET TYPE="text/css" HREF="/Sito/home/css/ApplicazioneHome.css"><!--  includo il JS di Servizio dinamicamente --><script type="text/javascript" src="/Sito/home/js/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Sito/home/js/toggle.js"></script>             <TITLE>Ser.P.I.Co. - Richiesta di RIMBORSO IVA TR       </TITLE></HEAD><BODY><div class="contenitore"><div id="testata">        <div id="testata_fondo_i">          <div id="testata_sx"><a href="http://www.agenziaentrate.gov.it/" title="Vai al sito dellazienda [Link a sito esterno]" target="_agenziaWindow"><img src="/Sito/home/immagini/logo.gif" alt="Sito dellazienda" border="0"></a></div>         <div id="testata_centro_i"></div>           <div id="testata_dx_i"></div>       </div>      <p id="titolo_servizio">        <!--  -->       </p></div>                      <LINK REL=STYLESHEET TYPE="text/css" HREF="/Sito/home/css/menu_dropDown.css"><!--[If lt IE 9]>     <LINK REL=STYLESHEET TYPE="text/css" HREF="/Sito/home/css/menu_dropDown_IElt9.css"><![endif]--> <!--[If IE 9]>     <LINK REL=STYLESHEET TYPE="text/css" HREF="/Sito/home/css/menu_dropDown_IE9.css"><![endif]--> <div class="menu_orizzontale"><div class="menu">   <ul class="blockeasing">        <li class="main">                 <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/RedirectServizi"> Home SERVIZI</a>        </li>        <li class="main">             <a href="#">Consultazioni</a>                 <ul class="subnav0">                      <li><a href="#"><u>Informazioni Generalizzate</u></a></li>                      <li><a href="/FamigliaFiscale/FamigliaFiscaleServlet">Famiglia Fiscale</a></li>                      <li><a href="/CollegamentoTerritorioWeb/TerritorioServlet">Catasto e Conservatorie</a></li>                      <li><a href="/EstremiDichiarazioni/EstremiServlet">Ricerca Documenti</a></li>                      <li><a href="/RichiesteMassive/MassiveServlet">Elaborazioni Massive</a></li>                      <li><a href="/ConsultazioniFATSC/FatscServlet">Dati rilevanti IVA - Portale F&C</a></li>                 </ul>        </li>        <li class="main">             <a href="#">Consultazioni Dati non A.T.</a>                 <ul class="subnav1">                      <li><a href="/CciaaConsultazioneWeb/CCIAAServlet">Camera di Commercio</a></li>                      <li><a href="/AciWeb/ACIServlet">Visure ACI</a></li>                      <li><a href="/InterrogaPEC/PecServlet">Posta Certificat@</a></li>                      <li><a href="/ContoEquitalia/EquitaliaServlet">Estratto Conto AdER</a></li>                 </ul>        </li>        <li class="main">             <a href="#">Consultazioni Sintetiche A.T.</a>                 <ul class="subnav2">                      <li><a href="/SinteticoVUC/SinteticoVUCServlet">Sintetico VUC</a></li>                 </ul>        </li>   </ul></div></div><div class="esci">        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/CloseSession"> Esci</a></div><div class="user">           Utente connesso <i><b>XXXXXX</b></i></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/Sito/home/js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">    $(document).ready(function() {      $("ul.blockeasing li.main").mouseover(function(){          $(this).find('.subnav0').stop().animate({height: '155px', opacity:'1'},{queue:false, duration:1500, easing: 'easeOutElastic'})         $(this).find('.subnav1').stop().animate({height: '107px', opacity:'1'},{queue:false, duration:1500, easing: 'easeOutElastic'})         $(this).find('.subnav2').stop().animate({height: '35px', opacity:'1'},{queue:false, duration:1500, easing: 'easeOutElastic'})    });      $("ul.blockeasing li.main").mouseout(function(){          $(this).find('.subnav0').stop().animate({height:'0px', opacity:'0'},{queue:false, duration:1600, easing: 'easeOutElastic'})         $(this).find('.subnav1').stop().animate({height:'0px', opacity:'0'},{queue:false, duration:1600, easing: 'easeOutElastic'})         $(this).find('.subnav2').stop().animate({height:'0px', opacity:'0'},{queue:false, duration:1600, easing: 'easeOutElastic'})    });    $("ul.blockeasing li").hover(function() {            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#F7F7F7"}, 600);},            function() {            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#FDAF7B"}, 600);    });  });</script>       <div class="menu_orizzontale_servizio"> <TABLE width="100%" align="left">       <tr>            <td class="utente">                 &nbsp;&nbsp;Sei in: <i><b>Consultazioni - Informazioni Generalizzate</b></i>            </td>                       <td class="barra">          </td>           <td class="barra">          </td>           <td class="barra">          </td>                           <td class="barra">          </td>           <td class="barra">                      <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=indiv">Ricerca</a>                      </td>           <td class="barra">              <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneGuidaServlet?Ric=IVR" target="_guidaWindow">Guida</a>          </td>           <td class="barra">                              <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=News" >News</a>         </td>                                                                           </tr>   </TABLE>    </div>          <div class="data">Data:<b>10/01/2020 09:58:42</b></div>                         <div class="centrato" align="center">   <div class="divisore_orizz">            <table cellpadding="3" summary="La tabella riporta gli estremi identificativi del contribuente interrogato">            <tr>                <td class="fissi">              Denominazione                           </td>               <td>IMPRESA XXXXXXXXXX SRL              </td>               <td class="fissi">                  Codice Fiscale              </td>               <td>xxxxxxxxxx              </td>           </tr>       </table>    </div>                                          </div>   <div class="wrapper">  <div align="center">            <div id="wait" style="display:none;width:90px;height:90px;position:relative;top:300px;left:100px;padding:2px;"><img src="/Sito/home/immagini/wait.gif" /><br>attendere...</div>     <div id="waittoolong" style="display:none;position:relative;top:300px;left:100px;padding:2px;" class="diagnostico"><br>impossibile soddisfare la richiesta nei tempi previsti</div>     <div id="ajaxerror" style="display:none;position:relative;top:300px;left:100px;padding:2px;" class="diagnostico"><br>problemi in fase di esecuzione della richiesta</div>   </div>              <div class="centrale_menu" id="centrale_menu"><a id="contenuto" name="contenuto"></a><!-- #BeginEditable "Contenuti" -->                        <div class="centrato" align="center">               <div class="datiTit">                       MODELLO                 IVA TR                  <br>        Richiesta di RIMBORSO o utilizzo in compensazione del Credito IVA Trimestrale                   </div>  <br>                    <div class="sinistra">                      Richiesta n. 19525144354 - 0000001 del 30/10/2019                                       presentata nell'ANNO                        <b>2019</b>      <br><br>               </div>              <div class="container_modelli_tabs" id="container_modelli_tabs">                                <!--  includo JS per il Menu Alto -->   <script type="text/javascript" src="/ApplicazioneUffici/js/menuAlto.js"></script>                           <div id="mainMenuAlto">             <table>    <tr>    <td valign="top">    <!-- tabella contenente le voci presenti per il documento -->   <table  class="dati"  summary="La tabella riporta le voci presenti per il documento">       <tr>        <!-- frontespizio -->               <td class="menuAlto" width="200px">                 <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=IVR&CF=xxxxxxxxxx&Anno=2019&Protocollo=T19103019525144354001&Quadro=">                      Frontespizio                </a>            </td>       </tr>       <!-- fine frontespizio -->                              <!-- dichiarazione presentata -->               <tr>        <!-- dichiarazione PRESENTATA-->            <td class="menuAlto_sel" width="200px">                 <a href="#" onClick="visualizzaMenuUp('MenuPresentato', 'menuUp')" title="Apri la Comunicazione Presentata">                         Richiesta Presentata               </a>            </td>       </tr>               <!-- fine dichiarazione presentata --></table>      </td>   <td valign="top">   <!-- inizio a trattare i DIV contenenti i singoli menu -->      <!-- MENU dichiarazione presentata -->      <DIV id="MenuPresentato" class="menuUp"         >       <FIELDSET class="form_menuAlto">            <LEGEND> Richiesta Presentata </LEGEND>                 <table  class="tabella_menuAlto" align="left">          <!-- DICHIARANTE -->        <TR class="riga_tabella_menuAlto">          <td width="50">             &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/ApplicazioneUffici/immagini/freccia.gif" border="0">             </td>           <TD class="fissi" nowrap="nowrap">              Quadri          </TD>           <td width="20">             <a                                                  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=IVR&CF=xxxxxxxxxx&Anno=2019&Protocollo=T19103019525144354001&stato=P&Quadro=TA&Modulo=1">                  TA              </A>            </TD>               <td width="20">             <a                                                  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=IVR&CF=xxxxxxxxxx&Anno=2019&Protocollo=T19103019525144354001&stato=P&Quadro=TB&Modulo=1">                  TB              </A>            </TD>               <td width="20">             <a                                                  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=IVR&CF=xxxxxxxxxx&Anno=2019&Protocollo=T19103019525144354001&stato=P&Quadro=TC&Modulo=1">                  TC              </A>            </TD>               <td width="20">             <a                                                  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=IVR&CF=xxxxxxxxxx&Anno=2019&Protocollo=T19103019525144354001&stato=P&Quadro=TD&Modulo=1">                  TD              </A>            </TD>               <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;            </td>       </TR>       <!-- fine DICHIARANTE -->       </table>        </FIELDSET> </div>      <!-- fine MENU dichiarazione presentata --> </td>   </tr>   </table>                </div>                  </div>  <br>            <div class="borderOption" id="borderOption">        <div class="dati_contenuto">                                                <!-- titolo quadro -->  <div class="sinistra">          <b> Quadro TD modulo 1 -            <i>Presupposti - Rimborso e/o conpensazione - Altri dati</i>            </b>            <br>    </div>                  <!--  STAMPA -->        <div class="destra">            <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=IVR&CF=xxxxxxxxxx&Anno=2019&Protocollo=T19103019525144354001&Quadro=TD&Modulo=1&stampa=P">              <img src="/Sito/consultazioni/immagini/printer.gif"  border="0" alt="Formato stampabile del quadro"> stampa         </a>        </div>  <br>    <!-- fine STAMPA -->        <div class="destra">            Importi in EURO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          <a  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=IVR&CF=xxxxxxxxxx&Anno=2019&Protocollo=T19103019525144354001&Quadro=TD&Modulo=1&valuta=L&stato=P&Riga=&Parte=">                converti in <font size="+1">£</font></a>    <br>    </div>                           <table width="100%" class="base" summary="La tabella riporta i dati del documento">                            <TR class="riga2_tabella">                                              <TD CLASS="fissi" align="left" width="10%">                     TD001                       </td>                                   <TD CLASS="fissi" align="right"  width="10%">                           001                     </TD>                       <TD  align="left"  width="60%">                  CASELLA ALIQUOTA MEDIA                     </TD>                       <TD align="right" class="importi">                          SI                      </td>                   </TR>                   <TR class="riga2_tabella">                                              <TD CLASS="trasparente" width="10%">                        </td>                                   <TD CLASS="fissi" align="right"  width="10%">                           002                     </TD>                       <TD  align="left"  width="60%">                  Aliquota media operaz. attive maggiorata 10%                       </TD>                       <TD align="right" class="importi">                                  2,07                        </TD>                   </TR>                   <TR class="riga2_tabella">                                              <TD CLASS="trasparente" width="10%">                        </td>                                   <TD CLASS="fissi" align="right"  width="10%">                           003                     </TD>                       <TD  align="left"  width="60%">                  Aliquota media operazioni passive                      </TD>                       <TD align="right" class="importi">                                 21,97                        </TD>                   </TR>                   <TR class="riga2_tabella">                                              <TD CLASS="fissi" align="left" width="10%">                     TD007                       </td>                                   <TD CLASS="fissi" align="right"  width="10%">                           001                     </TD>                       <TD  align="left"  width="60%">                  IMPORTO DA UTILIZZARE IN COMPENSAZIONE                     </TD>                       <TD align="right" class="importi">                      22.705,19                       </TD>                   </TR>                   <TR class="riga2_tabella">                                              <TD CLASS="fissi" align="left" width="10%">                     TD008                       </td>                                   <TD CLASS="fissi" align="right"  width="10%">                           007                     </TD>                       <TD  align="left"  width="60%">                  Codice fiscale professionista                      </TD>                       <td align="right" class="importi">                          <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=CF&CF=BRRMSMxxxxxxxx">BRRMSMxxxxxxxx</a>                        </td>                   </TR>                   <TR class="riga2_tabella">                                              <TD CLASS="trasparente" width="10%">                        </td>                                   <TD CLASS="fissi" align="right"  width="10%">                           008                     </TD>                       <TD  align="left"  width="60%">                  CASELLA FIRMA CAAF/PROFESSIONISTA                      </TD>                       <TD align="right" class="importi">                          SI                      </td>                   </TR>                   <tr class="riga_tabella_base">                      <td colspan="4">                        </td>                   </tr>                           </table>                                                                </div>  </div>      </div></div></div>      <div class="vociMenu">      <!-- Menù GENERALE -->       <!-- template relativo alla gestione delle voci di menu s sx -->                                               <h2 class="h2selezionato">Dati dei<BR>RIMBORSI</h2>                 <div class="datiMenu2Espansi">                                                              <!-- INIZIO AREE Rimb NORMALI -->                   <ul class="menu_ul">                                                                <li class="el_link_sel">                        <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Rimb&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                           Rimborsi                        </A>                        </li>                   <!-- INIZIO AREE RimbCF NORMALI -->                                                                     <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=RimbCF&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                         Rimborsi da Conto Fiscale                       </A>                    </li>                                               <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>           <!-- template relativo alla gestione delle voci di menu s sx -->                                           <h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">Informazioni<br>ANAGRAFICHE</a></h2>                <div class="datiMenu2">                                                             <!-- INIZIO AREE Ana NORMALI -->                    <ul class="menu_ul">            <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Ana&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                            Dati Anagrafici                     </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE AltreAna NORMALI -->               <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=AltreAna&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                           Altri dati Anagrafici                       </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE Rap NORMALI -->                <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Rap&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                            Rapporti con Altri                      </A>                    </li>                                               <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>       <!-- template relativo alla gestione delle voci di menu s sx -->                                           <h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">Informazioni<BR>REDDITUALI</a></h2>                 <div class="datiMenu2">                                                             <!-- INIZIO AREE Dich NORMALI -->                   <ul class="menu_ul">                                                                        <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Dich&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                           Dichiarazioni Fiscali                       </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE DichComu NORMALI -->                                                                           <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=DichComu&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                           Comunicazioni e Dichiarazioni                       </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE AltreDich NORMALI -->                                                                          <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=AltreDich&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                          Comunicazioni<br>per la richiesta di<br>Agevolazioni                        </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE DichOpAd NORMALI -->                                                                           <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=DichOpAd&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                           Opzioni e Adesioni                      </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE Camerali NORMALI -->                                                                           <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Camerali&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                           Dati Camerali                       </A>                    </li>                                               <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>       <!-- template relativo alla gestione delle voci di menu s sx -->                                           <h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">Dati delle<BR>RISCOSSIONI</a></h2>                  <div class="datiMenu2">                                                             <!-- INIZIO AREE RiscVU NORMALI -->                     <ul class="menu_ul">                                                                <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=RiscVU&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                         Riscossione<br>Spontanea                        </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE RiscRP NORMALI -->                                                                     <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=RiscRP&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                         Riscossione<br>Coattiva                     </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE F24Sel NORMALI -->                                                                     <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=F24Sel&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                         Ricerche tributi F24                        </A>                    </li>                                               <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>       <!-- template relativo alla gestione delle voci di menu s sx -->                                           <h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">ACCERTAMENTO e CONTENZIOSO</a></h2>                 <div class="datiMenu2">                                                             <!-- INIZIO AREE Acce NORMALI -->                   <ul class="menu_ul">        <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Acce&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                           Atti e Segnalazioni                     </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE AltriAcce NORMALI -->          <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=AltriAcce&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                          Altri atti                      </A>                    </li>                       <!-- INIZIO AREE Cont NORMALI -->           <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Cont&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                           Contenzioso                     </A>                    </li>                                               <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>       <!-- template relativo alla gestione delle voci di menu s sx -->                                           <h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">REGISTRO</a></h2>               <div class="datiMenu2">                                                             <!-- INIZIO AREE DichReg NORMALI -->                    <ul class="menu_ul">        <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=DichReg&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                            Atti e Successioni                      </A>                    </li>                                               <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>       <!-- template relativo alla gestione delle voci di menu s sx -->                                           <h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">ALTRE<br>Informazioni</a></h2>                  <div class="datiMenu2">                                                                 <!-- INIZIO SOTTO AREE Patrimoniali  -->                                                                    <h3 class="trigger">                    <a href="#">                        Dati<br>Patrimoniali                            </a>            </h3>               <div class="datiMenu3">             <ul class="menu_ul">                                                                                            <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Fab&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                                                             Catasto Urbano                                              </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Ter&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                                                             Catasto Terreni                                             </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Conserva&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                                                            Conservatorie                                               </a>                            </li>                                           <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>                                      <!-- INIZIO SOTTO AREE ComunicEE  -->                                                                   <h3 class="trigger">                    <a href="#">                        Comunicazioni<br>da Enti Esterni                            </a>            </h3>               <div class="datiMenu3">             <ul class="menu_ul">                                                                                            <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=PresEE&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                                                          Presenza sintetica                                              </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Art78&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                               <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Oneri<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Deducibili/<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Detraibili</em>                                             </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Beni&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                                <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Beni<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mobili/Leasing</em>                                             </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=AltreC&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                              <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comuni Ministeri<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enti Pubblici</em>                                              </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Sanit&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                               <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Strutture<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sanitarie</em>                                             </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Utenze&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                              <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Utenze</em>                                             </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=OpFin&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                               <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Op. Finanziari<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Assicurazioni<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enti Previdenziali</em>                                              </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=ComCre&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                              <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comunicazioni<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Crediti</em>                                               </a>                            </li>                                           <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>                                      <!-- INIZIO SOTTO AREE ScambiInEx  -->                                                                  <h3 class="trigger">                    <a href="#">                        Scambi Intra/Extra<br>comunitari                            </a>            </h3>               <div class="datiMenu3">             <ul class="menu_ul">                                                                                            <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=Dog&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                                                             Import/Export                                               </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=IvaIntra&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                                                            Iva Intracomunitaria                                                </a>                            </li>                                                                       <li class="el_link">                                        <a href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=BlackList&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                                                           Comunicazioni Black List                                                </a>                            </li>                                           <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>                                  <!-- INIZIO AREE EleTra NORMALI -->                     <ul class="menu_ul">            <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=EleTra&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                         Informazioni Elenchi Trasmessi                      </A>                    </li>                                               <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>       <!-- template relativo alla gestione delle voci di menu s sx -->                                           <h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">L'AGENZIA<br>scrive</a></h2>                <div class="datiMenu2">                                                             <!-- INIZIO AREE InvCom NORMALI -->                     <ul class="menu_ul">        <!-- non ci sono gestioni specifiche -->                                                                    <li class="el_link">                            <A  href="/ApplicazioneUffici/ApplicazioneWebServlet?Ric=InvCom&CF=xxxxxxxxxx">                         Invito alla Compliance                      </A>                    </li>                                               <li class="el_end"></li>                                    </ul>           </div>              </div></div></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. We need more information to understand your issue. What we need is things like, what have you tried so far? (show your code). example of HTML or website helps. If the issue is in your code, what is it and where? example of your expected output. As SO is not a code writing service, we will need this information to help you. Might be worth reading, how to as a question section

Comment: Well. I do a simple code   open "get","url,"false . Send  if . Status =200 then HTML.body.innerhtml=. Responsetext end if.  The responsetext Is ok cause i can fill a TXT file and a HTML too wich contains all the HTML tags...so when i use something likes getelementsbytagname i get the innerhtml, innertext, outertext and outer HTML  of TD, TR and so on but not  some of TR and TD that are insider the responsetext. I can t upload the TXT file/HTML because Is more than character limitpermitted...34656 more or less...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i do not know why but I resolved with this

```
 Dim fs As Object, a As Object, s As String
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("e:\test.txt", True)
Dim x As String
a.WriteLine Replace(Replace(Replace(Http.responseText, ",", ""), vbLf, ""), vbCr, "")
Set a = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
Open "e:\test.txt" For Input As #1
    Input #1, x
    oHTML.body.innerHTML = x
Close #1
```

Probably it would be a encoding problem o formatted ones. I had to create a file and put in responsetext as replaced ... with X= replace (bla bla bla) and ohtml.body.innerhtml= x problem not solved.
if someone have o will have an idea...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably truncated because the response from the website is being returned in Chunks.

Take a look at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893510/how-do-i-use-the-winhttp-api-with-transfer-encoding-chunked). It might help you understand the concept. With modern web browsers or some other programming languages, chunked transfer encoding is handled at a lower level behind objects and wrappers, but it might be winhttp or this particular api doesnt have this, so you'll need to accommodate in your own code.